# Adicionar um botão para excluir uma tarefa da minha lista de tarefas

Tags: javascript, html

Acrescentar um botão "X" ao lado de cada tarefa, que quando ativado ele exclui essa tarefa.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lista de Tarefa</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lista de Tarefa</h1>

    <input type="text" id="text" class="text" placeholder="Tarefa">

    <ul id="lista" class="lista"> </ul>

    <button onclick="adicionar()" id="adicionar">ADICIONAR</button>

    <script>
        function adicionar()
{
    let text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    let list = document.getElementById('lista').innerHTML;

    list += `<li> ${text}</li>`
    document.getElementById('lista').innerHTML = list;
}



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Evite usar `onclick`. Use `addEventListener`.